# Displaying user location in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

When this page is loaded, an alert asks you if you would like to let the website use your current address. I want to change this code so that when the user clicks okay, the address is posted to a paragraph tag in the body instead of the alert.

How would one go about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Reverse Geocoding</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">      </script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var geocoder;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lng = position.coords.longitude;
codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  console.log(results)
    if (results[1]) {
     //formatted address
     alert(results[0].formatted_address)
    //find country name
         for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
        for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

        //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                //this is the object you are looking for
                city= results[0].address_components[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //city data
    alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


    } else {
      alert("No results found");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
});
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 

</body> 
</html>
```

this is whats in my body section

```
<body>
<div>
    <p id="content1"></p>
    <p id="content2"></p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You'd just do `document.getElementById('some_element').innerHTML = city.short_name + " " + city.long_name` etc.

Comment: would document.write("city.short_name + " " + city.long_name"); work?

Comment: Nope, you should never use `document.write`, ever ever!

Comment: ok, what should the 'some_element' in your code be set to? Also which alert statements should i take out so the new text display takes precedence?

Answer (score 0):

You should put some elements in your body and write to them instead.

Since you are using jquery, you can access them with `$("#IDNAME")` selectors, and apply text changes to them with the `.text(NEWTEXT)` function, and comment out the alert functions so they do not activate.

Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/htthzx6a/

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">      </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
        }
        //Get the latitude and the longitude;
        function successFunction(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            codeLatLng(lat, lng)
        }

        function errorFunction() {
            alert("Geocoder failed");
        }

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



        }

        function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(results)
                    if (results[1]) {
                        //formatted address
                        alert(results[0].formatted_address)
                        $("#content1").text(results[0].formatted_address);
                        //find country name
                        for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                            for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {

                                //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                                    //this is the object you are looking for
                                    city = results[0].address_components[i];
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //city data
                        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)
                        $("#content2").text(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name);


                    } else {
                        $("#content1").text("No results found");
                        alert("No results found");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                    $("#content1").text("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div>
        <p id="content1"></p>
        <p id="content2"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well explained however i can't seem to get any output at all this way. any suggestions?

Comment: also i still want the original alert that the browser is going to use your address

Comment: Answer is amended to keep the values both printing to the screen and also alerting

Comment: Yes it works fine - alerts and also posts to my screen

Comment: for me, this code results in an immediate pop up with my location with out warning. Also there is no direct output i.e. a block of text . any clues??

Comment: Did you go to the fiddle? The location has no confirmation box because you have confirmed it in the past so it is not asking again. The fiddle has the text showing in the right side, so you can use a similar concept to that in your page. The script is currently configured to write into id=content1 and id=content2, you can adjust that to whatever you need.

Comment: yes I clicked the link and liked the results, and that was a good point about the browser saving the choice but still no text out put other than the alert.

Comment: You need an element of some sort with id=content1 and id=content2 or else it won't print out anywhere. You can also make these by doing $("body").append("<p id=content1>").append("<p id=content2>")

Comment: I'm still only getting the alert containing my location

Comment: Can you post your code for the html markup that should include id=content1 ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure whats wrong. Try just using the fiddle as your base or looking at the differences. Also note that I removed onload=initialize() from body and placed it at the bottom of the script

Comment: i added the code thats currently in my body section at the end of my original post. are you saying i need to add to it?

Comment: Hi, i modified the javascript of the fiddle a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/htthzx6a/1/

Comment: i noticed the jsfiddle link uses a regular body tag instead of the body onload tag. also still no display...?

Comment: thank you for you assistance. the j fiddle file breaks down the sections well but if you could please post the full file that works for you jQuery tags included? thanks. ill get it eventually...